# Yii2: Not able to send Email from form

Tags: php, mysql, email, yii2

```
<div class="status-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model,'job_code')->widget(Select2::classname(),[
            'data'=>ArrayHelper::map(CreateJob::find()->all(),'job_id','job_code'),
            'language'=>'en',
            'options'=>['placeholder' => 'Select Job Code','id'=>'empCode'],
            'pluginOptions' =>[

            ],
        ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'job_code')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'client_code')->textInput(['readonly' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput(['readonly' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_email')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_mobile')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_first_name')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'emp_last_name')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'job_description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->radioList(array('Approved'=>'Approved','Digital'=>'Digital','CDP'=>'CDP','Print'=>'Print','Other Process'=>'Other Process','Packing'=>'Packing','Dispatch'=>'Dispatch'),['class' => $model->status ? 'btn-group' : 'btn btn-default'],array('onChange'=>'toggleSSN();'),['id'=>'radioButtons'] );                   ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Status();
       $email = new Emails();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
        {

                $value=Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom(["xyz@gmail.com"])
                ->setTo($model->emp_email)
                ->setsubject('Job Status')
                ->setHtmlBody($model->job_description)
                ->send();

            $model->save();
            $email->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I want to send Email to the client about its current status of job. When user will paste submit it should send email to the client from filled  form fields.
Also I need to set template for this email so that only client information will change no other part.

Comment: why two mail functions in form and controller?

Comment: I just put it,is function in  controller enough?

Comment: You did not mention what error you are getting. Are the mail not sending. Also remove then unnecessary mail code form your form.

Comment: not able to send email, email is not sending

Comment: '  'mailer'=>[
        'class'=> 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'password' => '***',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ], '
this is in component

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary code where you are trying to display boolean value in your view, remove this:

```
<?= 
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com')
->setTo('abc@hotmail.com')
->setSubject('Message subject')
->setTextBody('Plain text content')
->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
->send();
?>
```

You should check what value returns your sending function by var_dump($value) in your controller, if it return false there is high probability that your server is not proper configured.

If you are using Ubuntu, read "How to install ssmtp" and "How to configure ssmtp" from: http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-ssmtp.html

Comment: First, change your password :P. second i forgot that it is not mail() function second set  'useFileTransport'=>'false' in your config:
 'components' => [
        ...
        'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
             'useFileTransport'=>'false'
         ],
],

Comment: did this changes but still not sending email :(

Answer (score 0):

First Remove div class="active form" from submit button then button will work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

to

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```